# How to use HYPERLINK and VLOOKUP on current cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink, excel-2007

Given this **Tracking** tab with a list:

[image]

How can i add a hyperlink, such that if i click **OBS1001**, it will point to this tab named **Repository**

[image]

I already used something like this `=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP("OBS1001";'Repository'!$B$3:$Y$1052;1;0);"OBS1001")` but i got `#N/A`

Answer (score 3):

`VLookup()` is only returning a value from sheet `Repository` which is not any valid reference for hyperlink. Try below formula-

```
=HYPERLINK("#Repository!A" & MATCH(A2,Repository!A:A,0),A2)
```

[image]

> ***Edit: `VBA` Approach.***

If you want to add hyperlinks to code cells then use below sub.

```
Sub AddHyperlinks()
Dim lRow As Long, hRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range

lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each Rng In Range("A2:A" & lRow)
        hRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Rng, Range("Repository!A:A"), 0)
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range(Rng.Address), _
                    Address:="#Repository!A" & hRow, _
                    ScreenTip:=Rng.Value2, _
                    TextToDisplay:=Rng.Value2
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any chance of targeting the Code column? I mean, I will directly add hyperlink on  Code column without adding new column and since i have more than 2000 items.

Comment: Then you have to use `VBA` macro. No way via formula.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlexanderPaudak Check my edited answer for `VBA` solution.

Comment: In excel, isn't it allowed for a tab name to have a space? for example my tab name is ```Selenium Repo```, If i use the one that you give ```=HYPERLINK("#Selenium Repo!A" & MATCH(A2,'Selenium Repo'!A:A,0),A2)``` it gives me ```reference not valid```

Comment: Yes, allow spaces. You need to qualify match function array range while using in VBA. Use like ` MATCH(A2,Range("'Selenium Repo'!A:A",0)`